# no match for queryset in UpdateView

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-views

The queryset in my view dont send back any result, however when Im executing the raw SQL command with DB Browser for example I have the result I want, I dont understnad why my queryset dont send back anything...

I got a **404 Not Found - No soldier to list found matching the query**

the view:

```
class EditUnitsToListUpdateView(UpdateView):


    model = SoldierToList
    fields = ('soldier', 'list', 'author')
    template_name = 'armybuilder_edit_unit_to_list.html'


    def get_queryset(self):
        print (self.model.objects.filter(list=54).query)

        return self.model.objects.filter(list=54)
```

My models:

```
class List(models.Model):
    faction = models.ForeignKey(Faction, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    format_points = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("home")



class Soldier(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    picture = models.FileField(blank=True,)
    points = models.IntegerField()
    factions = models.ManyToManyField(Faction)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class SoldierToList(models.Model):
    soldier = models.ForeignKey(Soldier, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    list = models.ForeignKey(List, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

My urls:

```
path('list/own/<int:list_id>/<int:faction_id>/addunit', AddUnitsToListFormView.as_view(), name='add_unit_to_list'),
path('list/own/<int:pk>/<int:faction_id>/editlist/toto', EditUnitsToListUpdateView.as_view(), name='edit_unit_to_list'),
```

The raw sql that work when executed separatly:

```
SELECT "armybuilder_soldiertolist"."id", "armybuilder_soldiertolist"."soldier_id", "armybuilder_soldiertolist"."list_id", "armybuilder_soldiertolist"."author_id" FROM "armybuilder_soldiertolist" WHERE "armybuilder_soldiertolist"."list_id" = 54
```

Thanks for your help guys and have a great day !

Comment: Note that Django will add extra filtering for the primary key (so it will add a `WHERE id=pk` (with `pk` the parameter in the URL). So it is definitely possible that this set is empty.

Comment: the WHERE is because I added a "filter" to my queryset no ?

Comment: well the `get_object()` will add an *extra* `WHERE` clause.

Comment: even if I use the query  return self.model.objects.all() I got nothing back 
only a Not Found: /armybuilder/list/own/54/4/editlist/toto on my logs

Comment: exactly because as said before, the *filtering* is not done (only) in `get_queryset`. The `get_object` function will see that there is a `pk` in the field parameters, and it will thus perform additional filtering.

Comment: I ended up doing 

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        print (SoldierToList.objects.filter(list=self.kwargs['pk']).query)
        obj = SoldierToList.objects.filter(list=self.kwargs['pk']).first()
        return obj

thanks :)